# Interact between Outlook and my WPF application

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, outlook

So, this may be a silly question (or something that's impossible), but I just wanted to ask in case anyone knows something. I'm trying to open Outlook (either through Office 365- Browser or through the Outlook Desktop Application) to compose an email. I got that working fine. What I want to know is, if there's a way that I can capture what was composed (like, Body, To, Subject, Attachments) in my WPF application so that I can update it on my end. Do you guys think if this is possible?

Here's the sample code I have: (For opening this in the browser)

```
        string To = "abc@ftr.com";
        string subject = "Test Email";
        string body = "This is a test email, Please ignore";
        string url = @"https://outlook.office.com/?path=/mail/action/compose&to=" + To + "&subject=" + subject + "&body=" + body;
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(url);
```

And here's the code for opening it in Outlook Desktop App:

```
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application oApp = new  Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem oMsg = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem)oApp.CreateItem(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
        oMsg.Subject = "subject something";
        oMsg.BodyFormat = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlBodyFormat.olFormatHTML;
        oMsg.HTMLBody = "Test Email";
        oMsg.Attachments.Add("c:/temp/test.txt", Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlAttachmentType.olByValue, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
        oMsg.Display(true);
```

Thank you!

Comment: It's definitely possible, I have done so in the past. Not near a pc atm, so can't check exactly but there is an event you can hook `ItemSend` that gives you the email as it will be send, you can even change the message before actually sending. (using COM Interop)

Comment: @Fixation: That's awesome we can do that. If you get a chance, can you help me get started ? Like do you have a sample code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hook the `ItemSend` event, which will give you a reference to the `MailItem` object that is about to be send. Here is some sample code I copied from the [Microsoft Community Forums](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/1785164b-3a0e-4a23-9062-15b3635d9fd5/is-it-possible-to-catch-send-event-on-outlook-addin-in-a-buttons-onaction-function?forum=outlookdev)

```
public void SendEnMail(Office.IRibbonControl control) //OnAction Function
{
    Outlook.Application oApp = new Outlook.Application();
    Outlook._MailItem myMail = (Outlook._MailItem)oApp.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
    myMail.Display(true);
    Outlook.Application application = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application;
    application.ItemSend += new Outlook.ApplicationEvents_11_ItemSendEventHandler(Application_ItemSend);
}
void Application_ItemSend(object Item, ref bool Cancel)
{
    string a = ((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem)Item).Body;
    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(a);
    Cancel = true;
}
```

Comment: Cool. Thank you. I know that this works for the Outlook desktop application. Does this work for the Outlook 365 (Browser) too?

Comment: You will need to write a javascript addon for that, got little experience dealing with the itemsend there, [here is a link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/outlook-on-send-addins?tabs=windows).